# Прошу помощи с регулярным выражением

Tags: регулярные-выражения

нужна регулярка которая бы группировала результат вмести с AND, должно выглядить что то типо такого: (выделил жирным, что конктретно я хочу вырезать с помощью регулярки)

**table1.name = :A2 AND** table1.product_name= :A1 AND table1.tikect IS NOT NULL AND table1.age IS NOT NULL AND table1.number= table2.number

исходная строка:
table1.name = :A2 AND table1.product_name= :A1 AND table1.tikect IS NOT NULL AND table1.age IS NOT NULL AND table1.number= table2.number

```
([\w\.\=\:\s]+AND)
```

пытался сделать так, но эта регулярка выдерается всё до последнего AND, а мне нужно до первого.

Comment: замените `AND` на `AND\n`, или поясните, что значит "брала значения до конца AND"

Comment: @teran чуть поправил описание, а причём тут новая строка? у меня всё в одной строке

Comment: `/^.+AND (.+)$/$1/U`

Comment: @Akina `.+` в начале не имеет смысла. лучше `\b`

Comment: @Akina спасибо, чуть поправил (^.+AND|^.*$)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы не захватывало ненужное, можно сделать квантификатор «ленивым»:

```
([\w\.\=\:\s]+?AND)
```

Но лучше, наверное, сделать регулярку более строгой, если шаблон подходит:

```
\w+\.\w+= :\w+ AND
```